# Count the number of filtered values

Tags: desktop-application, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a table has 2 columns:

[image]

I want to summarize these data in new table as follow:

[image]

what is the expression will help to do this?

I dont need to use the **MATRIX**

Regards,

Comment: If you don't want to use a Matrix, create a measure for each column: i.e the expression for New should be `New=COUNTAX(Table,[Col2]="New")`. Use each measure in the visualization you need.

Comment: A Matrix seems the easy solution.

Comment: here is my solution that helped me out to do the needful, Matrix is nothing for the required.
http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/count-number-of-filtered-rows/m-p/86501#M36295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution that helped me out to do the needful, Matrix is nothing for the required.

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/count-number-of-filtered-rows/m-p/86501#M36295